# Clang, link time optimization fails for AVX horizontal add

Tags: optimization, linker, clang, avx

I have a small piece of testing code which calculates the dot products of two vectors with a third vector using AVX instructions (A dot C and B dot C below). It also adds the two products, but that is just to make the function return something for this example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

double compute(const double *x)
{
  __m256d A = _mm256_loadu_pd(x);
  __m256d B = _mm256_loadu_pd(x + 4);
  __m256d C = _mm256_loadu_pd(x + 8);

  __m256d c1 = _mm256_mul_pd(A, C);
  __m256d c2 = _mm256_mul_pd(B, C);

  __m256d tmp = _mm256_hadd_pd(c1, c2);

  __m128d lo = _mm256_extractf128_pd(tmp, 0);
  __m128d hi = _mm256_extractf128_pd(tmp, 1);

  __m128d dotp = _mm_add_pd(lo, hi);

  double y[2];
  _mm_store_pd(y, dotp);

  return y[0] + y[1];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const double v[12] = {0.3, 2.9, 1.3, 4.0, -1.0, -2.1, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.3, 1.2};

  double x = 0;
  std::cout << "AVX" << std::endl;
  x = compute(v);

  std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile as

```
clang++ -O3 -mavx main.cc -o main
```

everything works fine. If I enable link time optimization:

```
clang++ -flto -O3 -mavx main.cc -o main
```

I get the following error "LLVM ERROR: Do not know how to split the result of this operator!". I have narrowed the culprit to the `_mm256_hadd_pd` statement. If this is exchanged with e.g. _m256_add_pd link time optimization works again. I realize that this is a silly example to use link-time optimization for, but the error ocurred in a different context where it link-time optimization is extremely helpful.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: "LLVM ERROR" means that this is a bug inside clang. Try to upgrade to the latest version of clang.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a bug in clang where the avx flags are not passed to the linker (at least according to this bug http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18808). For the record it seems to be present still in the Apple provided clang based on LLVM 3.5svn.